# remedy for academic gap year in interview

Tags: resume, job-search

I've a year gap in my class 12, my results were bad in test so I decided to sit and prepare for another year, and after passing my +2 I took admission in a college and after 1 year I left that college and took admission in another college in some different course, but to my utter dismay I failed in several papers and had to clear all those back papers for  1 year, which made my graduation duration 5 years. After this incidence i was shattered but didn't give up my studies and pursued my post graduations from a reputed university. Now i'm getting call for interviews from big PSUs. So my question is that, wad'll i say to the interview board if they ask about my academic gap years, please friends help me so that i can land on a good job and pursue my career with flying colors....

Comment: There are [many questions on this topic](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=gap+year) already. Voting to close.

Comment: @DavidK i confirm that it's not a duplicate, yes, it has happened in my life, if you or anybody else have answer to my question then plz help

Comment: @koustav11 fortunately, you're not alone -- someone else had this problem before you and asked a question here about it.  Check out the answers to the duplicate question.  Welcome to The Workplace, and good luck in your job search!

Comment: @koustav11 You "confirm" that this is not a duplicate, despite there being [45 questions](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=gap+year+is%3Aquestion) on the topic of career gap? Have you even read the answers to the question that DavidK linked to?

Comment: Some of the way you worded this ("utter dismay", "failed", "shattered") makes you sound really worried about having taken a year off. This worriedness is the real problem, not anything else. Try this - assume it's not a problem that you took a year off, and then write down a simple explanation of why you took that year off. Read what you wrote out loud, as if you're sitting in an interview room. That's what you'll say in the interview when they ask you about it.